# Getting image path from MongoDB using handlebars

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

I stored the image path in MongoDB but when I'm trying to get the image path into the src attribute of the img tag, it keeps inserting apostrophes at the beginning and the end of the image path.

```
<img src=“{{ this.img }}” alt="Alt text">
```

Viewed from Chrome Dev Tools:

```
<img src="'/img/thisisanimage.jpg'" alt="Alt text">
```

Any reason why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

you should use it like this:
`<img src="{{ img.src }}" alt="Image is broken" />`

Comment: Weird! it works well with me in handelbars playground. are you sure you put it like this `<img src="{{ this.img }}" alt="Alt text">`

Comment: yeah. Also, I double checked the db to make sure it wasn’t saved with the apostrophes. They’re still being inserted into the src attribute.